# Portable Class Library in Monodevelop:incompatible target framework

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I get this error when trying to compile the portable class library for my mono project.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.9\lib\mono\xbuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.0\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by PortableTest.csproj: Imported project: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.9\lib\mono\xbuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.0\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" does not exist. (PortableTest)
```

I use the modified 3.1.1 version of Monodevelop supporting portable class library and I think it was working before I reinstall mono. I suppose the folder has been deleted.

Is there an easy way to be able to compile a portable library in monodevelop again?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try targeting the system (Microsoft) .NET framework instead of the Mono .NET framework.

Comment: The portable project is built, but I get "incompatible target framework" when I want to add the reference. I'd like to target Mono for my gtk project.

Comment: Ah, then you need to install http://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/MonoDevelop-3.1.1.dmg which fixes the "incompatible target framework" referencing bug.

Comment: Seems to work on Mac, but here on windows the patched version doesn't seems to recognize the portable framework.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ! I was targeting Mono/.Net 3.5 instead of 4.0. So, no incompatibility problem now. But the folder is still missing! So PortableTest can't build.

Comment: Mono doesn't have the PCL assemblies, so you have to target the Microsoft .NET runtime on Windows. You can change this by doing Project -> Active Runtime and selecting the Microsoft .NET runtime.

Comment: Ok, I have to build from .Net Framework then switch to Mono. Thank you.